# How to access dynamic array key and value

Tags: php

```
array:1 [▼
 0 => array:4 [▼
   "firstName" => "val"
   "email" => "someval"
   "phone" => "someval"
   "zip" => "someval"
 ]
]
```

I have the above array created dynamically. For e.g firstName, email fields may change sometimes 4 elements and sometimes 12 elements. Not sure how to access the key and respective values.

Comment: Have you tried with `foreach($the_array as $key=>$value) {...}`?

Comment: With foreach as Jimmy suggests, or if you know the position use $firstname = $myArray[0]['firstName'];

Comment: @JimmyAdaro. Yes I tried it but I'm getting the value as 0. I think its top level index key.

Comment: @jannej. As I mentioned firstName may change in array. It's dynamic array. firstName will change to lastName or someother else also.Its unknown

Comment: Then you have to loop over it with foreach(). Eventually, you have to check for some value. You can try to access the first position like $myArray[0][0] but I would not recommend it.

Comment: appending to jimmy answer try  this one foreach($the_array as $key=>$value) {if(is_array($value)){ foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){...}}}

Comment: @MohdSadiq. Thanks your solution works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make out which part of the array is supposed to be dynamic, but here are a few examples for what I think might be your case:

1. The presence of a key, e.g. "email" is dynamic, you want to find the subarrays containing that key

   ```
   $data = [
       [
           'name' => 'Baz',
           'email' => 'test@example.com',
       ],
       [
           'name' => 'Foo',
       ],
   ];

   $dataWithEmail = [];
   foreach ($data as $item) {
       if (array_key_exists('email', $item)) {
           $dataWithEmail[] = $item;
       }
   }
   var_dump($dataWithEmail);

   // alternatively you can use:

   $dataWithEmail = [];
   $dataWithEmail = array_filter(
       $data,
       function($item) {
           return array_key_exists('email', $item);
       }
   );
   var_dump($dataWithEmail);
   ```
2. The depth of the array is dynamic and you want to find the "email"

   ```
   $data = [
       [
           [
               [
                   'name' => 'Bar',
                   'email' => 'bar@example.com',
               ],
           ],
       ],
       [
           [
               'name' => 'Foo',
               'email' => 'foo@example.com',
           ],
       ],
   ];

   $emails = [];
   array_walk_recursive(
       $data,
       function ($item, $key) use (&$emails) {
           if ('email' === $key) {
               $emails[] = $item;
           }
       }
   );
   var_dump($emails);
   ```
3. You have an array and you want to reduce it to only the values from a key (if it exists):

   ```
   $data = [
       [
           'name' => 'Baz',
           'email' => 'test@example.com',
       ],
       [
           'name' => 'Foo',
       ],
   ];

   $onlyEntriesWithNames = array_filter(
       $data,
       function ($item) {
           return array_key_exists('name', $item);
       }
   );
   $namesFromArray = array_reduce(
       $onlyEntriesWithNames,
       function($carry, $item) {
           $carry[] = $item['name'];

           return $carry;
       },
       []
   );
   var_dump($namesFromArray);
   ```